# how to add uinavigationcontroller as a second view not as rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

i know how to add uinavigationcontroller as root view and also how to push view in uinavigationcontroller.

What i am confused in the first view which is a root view is a simple view with button when this button is tapped it will show second view.

I want this second view as uinavigationview.

any ideas how to do it, i tried to search for the solution but didn't get any nor any similar question is asked before.

basically i am trying to work without interface builder to learn things in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are presenting the 2nd view controller modally

instead of

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

do:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

Comment: no i don't want to present it modally it will be permanently displayed  ... thanks for the answer.